# where is the documentation for add_action() parameters?

Tags: actions, documentation

I am reading the source of a plugin (gallery to slideshow plugin) to make it behave like i want and it is using an action

```
add_action( 'the_posts', array( &$this, 'have_gallery' ), 10, 1 );
```

I want to know what those extra parameters (10,1) mean but i cant find the documentation of this action. Please help

Comment: It's helpful to search Google with the function name: add_action WordPress. Most functions are pretty well documented in the Codex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those parameters aren't unique to the_posts, they're parameters for the add_action() function

```
add_action( $tag, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

the 10 is just the default priority and 1 is the default number of accepted arguments.  since they're both default, you don't really need either.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: Ok nice, But what does this hook do?

Comment: did you check the codex?  add_action adds a function to a wordpress action.  so your plugin is telling wordpress to run its 'have_gallery' function when wordpress runs the the_posts() action

Comment: By the way, if you check the source for add_action, you'll see it uses ksort on the plugin event array per each event. This means that negative values are possible and will sort higher than zero. PHP5 will let you create a key with the max negative value of -1410065407. So, if you hook the init event with that priority, it will likely be the first event ever run. Just remember that if you don't need that early of a priority, go with something in the 10+ range. In my case, I needed it to build a plugin to block bad spiders.

Answer (score 2):

This is rather [add_action()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) related.

```
add_action( 
   'the_posts', //$tag
   array( &$this, 'have_gallery' ), //$function_to_add
   10, //$priority - run priority, when to execute given action 
   1 //$accepted_args - number of accepted arguments, one in this case
);
```

10 means default run priority and 1 stands for one argument that this function takes.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response. But i wonder how on earth the plugin writer came across this hook and used it without documentation.